Does Shafi school of thought only make people of the book Dhimmi and pay jizya is there a different of option in this issue in the Shafi school
I was wondering if Shafi school only allow people of the book to be Dhimmi and pay jizya is their a different opinion in the school that says all non Muslims can be Dhimmi.
Also if this is true how did the Indonesias treat the Hindus and Buddhist as Indonesia practices the Shafi school and did they make them pay jizya

It helps however was there still any difference of opinion in the Shafi school about if polytheists pay the jizya like scholars etc
